# Android - Eclipse: Importing package from one project to another

Tags: android, eclipse

I have two projects (let's say project A and project B) and I have to merge those two, for that I want the package of project B to be included in project A. How to do it? Please help me..

Comment: I am using eclipse adt..

Comment: you could have tried that before posting a question here..

Comment: Ya of course, but this may help others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.. Just copy the package from project B and paste it in source of project A, and also if project B was referring any other project; do the same for project A also, then open the java classes and resolve the errors.